# Java - How do I verify alt text appears when mouse hovers over a button?

Tags: java, javascript, junit, webdriver, smartgwt

I am testing a site written in Javascript, by writing (very simple) Java tests in Eclipse and running them as JUnit tests.

As I am almost completely new to Java, I am encountering problems all over the place. For example: on the webpage, there are a few buttons that have alt-text that appears if the mouse is hovered over the buttons for half a second.

I use Selenium IDE 1.0.10 to get the scLocator IDs, but it does not pick up the ID for the alt-text pop-up. If, in the Selenium IDE, I use `"mouseOver"` or `"mouseOverAndWait"`, nothing happens. The test does not fail, as the element is present, yet the alt-text does not appear.

What java command can I use for `mouseOver`? I guess I can use `"assertScElementPresent('', 10*SECONDS);"` once I find the element, but what command can I use in java to simulate a mouse hover over a button?

I hope the question is clear and makes sense.

Comment: What exactly to you mean with "alt text"? Do you mean the HTML `alt` attribute? Buttons don't have `alt` attributes, only `img` elements do. Also there is no requirement for browsers to show them as tool tips (even if many do), because that is not their purpose. There is a `title` attribute, that is more likely (but still not mandatorily) displayed as a tool tip, and it applies to buttons. And it's unlikely that it's possible to check these tool tips with Selenium, because they are usually shown as OS based tool tips without any JavaScript interface that could control them in any way.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant that alternative text that appears for img elements. The button image has alternative text when hovering the mouse over it. I think I am using the wrong name for it. Either way, the command for hovering is, as I found it, `scElement("elementID").hover();`

Comment: That means you are using some tool tip library. You'd probably have to say which one.

Comment: You are probably right, but I have no idea which one is used. I guess I'll have to ask the programmers. Either way, thank you for all your help, Sir.

Comment: @RoToRa Actually, the INPUT element can take an ALT attribute if its type is set to `image`.  Thus: `<input type="image" src="foo.png" alt="Self Destruct" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to say "title" attribute, instead of alternate text?  Hovering over a button displays the title.  The img alt attribute (alt attribute) is used if the browser cannot find the image resource--it then displays the alt text.  I don't know what your ids are, so I'm assuming you are using a LinkButton control with an Image control inside of it given your details.  I have two solutions below.  If you're using this for using the variable later, then use the first answer by using an Accessor and an Action.  If you are just validating the UI, then use the second answer, which would be an Assert (validation command) alone.

**ASP.NET code:**

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText="img text" ToolTip="button" ImageUrl="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" />
        </asp:LinkButton>

**Rendered HTML code:**

<a id="LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton1','')"><img id="Image1" title="button" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="img text" /></a>
        <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" />

**#1 (Accessor & Action):**

Command: storeText
Target: xpath=//img[@id='Image1']/@title
Value: var_img_title

Command: type
Target: TextBox1
Value: ${var_img_title}

**#2 (Assert):**

Command: assertAttribute
Target: xpath=//img[@id='Image1']/@title
Value: button